# Is a lock possible per instance of an object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have understood that `lock()` locks a region of lines of code, other threads cannot access the locked line(s) of code. EDIT: this turns out to be just wrong.
Is it also possible to do that *per instance* of an object? EDIT: yes, that's is just the difference between static and non-static.

E.g. a `null` reference is checked during a lazy load, but in fact there is no need to lock other objects of the same type?

```
object LockObject = new object();
List<Car> cars;
public void Method()
{
   if (cars == null)
   {
      cars = Lookup(..)
      foreach (car in cars.ToList())
      {
          if (car.IsBroken())
          {
             lock(LockObject)
              {
                 cars.Remove(car)
              }
           }
       }
    }
    return cars;
}
```

EDIT, would this be a correct way to write this code:
Because when `cars == null` and thread A locks it, then another thread B will wait. Then when A is ready, B continues, but should check again whether `cars == null`, otherwise the code will execute again.
But this looks unnatural, I never saw such a pattern.
Note that locking the first `null`-check would mean that you acquire a lock even to check for `null` and every time again and again .. so that is not good.

```
public void Method()
{
   if (cars == null)
   {
      lock(LockObject)
      {
         if (cars == null)
         {
            cars = Lookup(..)
            foreach (car in cars.ToList())
             {
               if (car.IsBroken())
               {
                   cars.Remove(car)
               }
             }
          }
       }
    }
    return cars;
}
```

Comment: It *is* locking per instance, as you have it. There's a different `LockObject` for each instance. Only if `LockObject` was static would it be locked for the entire type.

Comment: Your code isn't thread safe. When two or more threads call `Method` simultaneously, `cars` could be initialized multiple times and also note that you can't remove elements from a collection while iterating it using foreach.

Comment: @MWatson Are you sure, that other instances can remove, while the lock is in place for a particular instance? I thought the line of code was locked for everyone.

Comment: for everyone accessing that code on the same instance - as it is an instance method - and not coming from the same thread.

Comment: @SSakthivel How would you do it, lock almost the whole method? I thought  one has to lock as little as possible.

Comment: @All Please have a look at my edit, my question has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to realise that locking is very much a matter of the object locked on.

Most often we want to lock particular blocks of code entirely. As such we use a readonly field to lock a section and hence prevent any other running of that code either at all (if the field is static) or for the given instance (if the field is not static). However, that is a matter of the most common use, not the only possible use.

Consider:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<int>> idLists = SomeMethodOrSomething();
List<int> idList;
if (idLists.TryGetValue(someKey, out idList))
{
  lock(idList)
  {
    if (!idList.Contains(someID))
      idList.Add(someID);
  }
}
```

Here "locked" section can be called simultaneously by as many threads as you can get going. It cannot, however, be called simultaneously on the same list. Such a usage is unusual, and one has to be sure that nothing else can try to lock on one of the lists (easy if nothing else can access `idLists` or access any of the lists either before or after they are added into it, hard otherwise), but it does come up in real code.

But the important thing here is that obtaining the `idList` is itself threadsafe. When it came to creating a new `idList` this more narrowly-focused locking would not work.

Instead we'd have to do one of two things:

The simplest is just lock on a readonly field before any operation (the more normal approach)

The other is to use `GetOrAdd`:

```
List<int> idList = idLists.GetOrAdd(someKey, () => new List<int>());
lock(idList)
{
  if (!idList.Contains(someID))
    idList.Add(someID);
}
```

Now an interesting thing to note here is that `GetOrAdd()` doesn't guarantee that if it calls the factory `() => new List<int>()` that the result of that factor is what will be returned. Nor does it promise to call it only once. Once we move away from the sort of code that just `lock`s on a readonly field the potential races get more complicated and more thought has to go into them (in this case the likely thought would be that if a race means more than one list is created, but only one is ever used and the rest get GC'd then that's fine).

To bring this back to your case. While the above shows that it's possible to lock not just as finely as your first example does, but much more finely again, the safety of it depends on the wider context.

Your first example is broken:

```
cars = Lookup(..)
foreach (car in cars.ToList()) // May be different cars to that returned from Lookup. Is that OK?
{
    if (car.IsBroken()) // May not be in cars. Is that OK?
    { // IsBroken() may now return false. Is that OK?
       lock(LockObject)
```

When the `ToList()` is called it may not be calling it on the same instance that was put into `cars`. This is not **necessarily** a bug, but it very likely is. To leave it you have to **prove** that the race is safe.

Each time a new `car` is obtained, again `cars` may have been over-written in the meantime. Each time we enter the lock the state of `car` may have changed so that `IsBroken()` will return false in the meantime.

It's possible for all of this to be fine, but showing that they are fine is complicated.

Well, it tends to be complicated when it is fine, sometimes complicated when it's not fine, but most often it's very simple to get the answer, "no, it is not okay". And in fact that is the case here, because of one last point of non-thread-safety that is also present in your second example:

```
if (cars == null)
{
  lock(LockObject)
  {
     if (cars == null)
     {
        cars = Lookup(..)
        foreach (car in cars.ToList())
         {
           if (car.IsBroken())
           {
               cars.Remove(car)
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
return cars; // Not thread-safe.
```

Consider, thread 1 examines `cars` and finds it null. Then it obtains a lock, checks that `cars` is still null (good), and if it is it sets it to a list it obtained from `Lookup` and starts removing "broken" cars.

Now, at this point thread 2 examines `cars` and finds it not-null. So it returns `cars` to the caller.

Now what happens?

1. Thread 2 can find "broken" cars in the list, because they haven't been remove yet.
2. Thread 2 can skip past cars because the list's contents are being moved by `Remove()` around while it is working on it.
3. Thread 2 can have the enumerator used by a `foreach` throw an exception because `List<T>.Enumerator` throws if you change the list while enumerating and the other thread is doing that.
4. Thread 2 can have an exception thrown that `List<T>` should never throw because Thread 1 is half-way in the middle of one of its methods and its invariants only hold before and after each method call.
5. Thread 2 can obtain a bizarre franken-car because it read part of a car before a `Remove()` and part after it. (Only if the the type of `Car` is a value-type; reads and writes of references is always individually atomic).

All of this is obviously bad. The problem is that you are setting `cars` before it is in a state that is safe for other threads to look at. Instead you should do one of the following:

```
if (cars == null)
{
  lock(LockObject)
  {
    if (cars == null)
    {
      cars = Lookup(..).RemoveAll(car => car.IsBroken());
    }
  }
}
return cars;
```

This doesn't set anything in `cars` until after the work on it has been done. As such another thread can't see it until it's safe to do so.

Alternatively:

```
if (cars == null)
{
  var tempCars = Lookup(..).RemoveAll(car => car.IsBroken());
  lock(LockObject)
  {
    if (cars == null)
    {
      cars = tempCars;
    }
  }
}
return cars;
```

This hold the lock for less time, but at the cost of potentially doing wasteful work just to throw it away. If it's safe to do this at all (it might not be) then there's a trade-off between potential extra time on the first few look-ups for less time in the lock. It's some times worth it, but generally not.

Comment: Indeed - how complicated this can be. Do you know whether MS `Lazy` does it correct, i.e. does it use a temp-list until it is ready?

Comment: Of the three modes Lazy supports, one has no locking, and the other two are like the two last (good) examples in this answer, both done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy to perform lazy initializing is by using properties for fields:

```
private List<Car> Cars
{
    get
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            return cars ?? (cars = Lockup(..));
        }
    }
}
```

Using your lock object here also makes sure, that no other thread also creates an instance of it.

Add and remove operations have also to be performed while locked:

```
void Add(Car car)
{
    lock(lockObject) Cars.Add(car);
}

void Remove(Car car)
{
    lock(lockObject) Cars.Remove(car);
}
```

Recognize the use of the `Cars` property to access the list!

Now you can get a copy of your list:

```
List<Car> copyOfCars;
lock(lockObject) copyOfCars = Cars.ToList();
```

Then it is possible to safely remove certain objects from the original list:

```
foreach (car in copyOfCars)
{
    if (car.IsBroken())
    {
        Remove(car);
    }
}
```

But be sure to use your own `Remove(car)` method which is locked inside.

Especially for `List` there is another possibility to cleanup elements inside:

```
lock(lockObject) Cars.RemoveAll(car => car.IsBroken());
```